# My divs are upside down

Tags: php, javascript, css

So I'm looping through some values, and putting them in graph form inside a div. For some reason, though, they are going from the tops of the divs to the bottom. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div id="div1" style="height:50px;width:70px;background:yellow; "
</div>

    <?php
    $n=0;
      for ( ;$n< $total_pages; ++$n) {

    $previous_views= mysql_query("SELECT `$n` FROM `books`.`$thisone` WHERE       `$thisone`.`$thisone` =0");
    $resultedin = mysql_fetch_row($previous_views);
    $fullresult=implode("','",$resultedin);

    ?>


 <script>

    var highview = '<?php echo $highest_views ; ?>'; 
    var mything='<?php echo $fullresult ; ?>';
    var pagestotal='<?php echo $total_pages ; ?>';
    var thewidth=70/pagestotal; 
    var m = mything/highview;
    var h = m*50;
    for ( i=0; i<1; i++){
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.style.width = thewidth+"px";
      div.style.height = h+"px";
      div.style.background = "green";
      div.style.float = "left";

      var element=document.getElementById("div1");
      element.appendChild(div);
    }
    </script>
        <?php


        }
    ?>
```

EDIT: I took out "float" and added 
`div.style.display = "inline-block";`
, just in case anyone else has similar troubles. Thanks to everyone anyways for their input, I'll look into updating my SQL.

Comment: You are using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Consider change to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: What about adding a sort (`ORDER BY`) in MySQL query?

Comment: uhh, no one mentioned moving the query outside of the loop?

Comment: Well no, I mean the values are coming in in the right order, it's just that the individual divs based on the values coming back are upside down. I only included the SQL for context. Thanks for the tip about the update in my syntax, though.

Comment: @mike: this `ORDER` is not necessary, I haven't noticed that this query returns one element only and is in the loop.

Comment: You haven't completed your opening `div` tag. Also, i'm not sure I completely understand the issue, but have you tried prepending rather than appending?

Comment: Why are you outputting a script for each row, instead of just outputting the HTML directly?

Comment: Not entirely clear on the differences of prepend/append. Basically the issue is, I'm looping through values and placing them into a div with a predefined width/height, but the bars of the graph descend from the top of the graph rather than go upwards. It's an issue of where they believe their base is, and I don't know how to set it differently.

Comment: Additionally, I'll add that the float style is what's doing this- without it, they go like I want them to, but with about 5 pixels of unwanted space between them. I'm probably missing something painfully obvious. And the script for each loop is because each height is different, and this is what I came up with.

Comment: @DaveChen I think a query inside the loop is correct.  He's using the loop variable to define the query.  Agreed, this can be done much more efficiently though...